# Is there a best practice schema.xml for SOLR when importing rich documents?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

I'm working with SOLR on a project where we import a bunch (~40k items) of rich documents, mainly MS Word, Powerpoint, Excel and PDFs.

**Is there a best practice `schema.xml` and/or `solrconfig.xml` to use in SOLR when using the `ExtractingRequestHandler`?**

I have been doing tweaks to the default schema to attempt to get facets working on date modification times, but even without that, I figure there could very well exist a good example of how these files should be when the default output from Tika is enough.

If there is no such thing as a best-practice `schema.xml` and/or `solrconfig.xml` I'm also interested in good examples, preferably from existing open source projects or even good blog posts.

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In the books Taming Text (http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/) you have some reference to 
ExtractingRequestHandler. This book it's about processing text using open source tools such as solr, tika or lucene.

I've read until chapter 5 and until now the book explain how extends the solr functionality by modifing the file schema.xml for create diferents type of fields, and procesing in query or indexing.

Comment: Ok, if you find something concerning best practices or so, be sure to update your answer. Thanks